# Enviar objeto via POST entre Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho dois arquivos JavaScript e preciso enviar um objeto do `arquivo1.js` para o `arquivo2.js` via POST, isso é possível?

Comment: Podes explicar a funcionalidade que estás a implementar e onde precisas disto? ajax entre ficheiros javascript não faz muito sentido ( a não ser que estejas a falar de NodeJS)

Comment: Bem, é que estou gerando vários botões através de um `for` no `onclick` dele quero enviar um objeto, mas não tem funcionado muito bem, apenas quando envio uma propriedade apenas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você está tentando fazer não faz muito sentido, se você está lidando com JavaScript, faça a comunicação via objetos e funções. POST é um verbo HTTP para se comunicar com o servidor. Fazendo uma analogia, seria como usar um celular para se comunicar com alguém que está do seu lado.

---

Ainda assim, se você precisa fazer comunicação via POST usando somente JavaScript, existe um plugin do jQuery chamado [mockAjax](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax). Como o nome diz, é usado para simular requisições AJAX, principalmente no inicio do desenvolvimento de uma aplicação Web, para testes unitários ou para manter responsabilidades separadas - o desenvolvedor front-end não precisa se preocupar com o que o desenvolvedor back-end vai desenvolver, ele simula as requisições do servidor para poder deixar a interface gráfica funcionando mesmo sem uma aplicação servidor. Fiz um [fiddle com um exemplo desse plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/9tef0chv/), mas o código é simples assim:

```
 $.mockjax({
    url: '/url/servico',
    dataType: 'json',
    response: function (settings) {
        // o parâmetro recebido do $.post
        var param = settings.data;
        this.responseText = {
            umaPropriedade: 'random ' + Math.random(),
            outraProp: settings.data.foo
        };
    }
 });

 var parametro = { foo: 'val'};
 $.post('/url/servico', parametro, function(data) {
    alert(data.umaPropriedade);
 });
```